# Where can I ask the question about psychology?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

Where can I ask [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25463/why-the-first-attempt-is-more-successfull-than-most-subsequent-ones)?

I thought it was clearly about gaming, but moderators closed it as offtopic and I don't know where to ask it. Psychology SE is early in Area51. What SE could I use instead?

(I believe that every good answerable question should have a StackExchange for it)

Update: The question got deleted (even StackPrinter fails to find it), so summarizing it here:

```
Why, when I play some game, is the first play attempt
more successful than the subsequent ones?
Only after 10-20 tries it begins to "recover" to original level.

Is it some well-known effect or is it just me?
```

The question is still open for me BTW

Comment: May be there should be "offtopic.stackexchange.com" to have a place for good questions, but not on topic on existing SEs?

Comment: And where do you go to express frustration with a certain topic when you keep running into a brick wall, nobody can help you, and your problem seems to be impossible with no solution?

Comment: Is this question posted somewhere? Because I would like to upvote it.
I also often experience "beginner's luck".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The place for psychological questions in general is [Cognitive Sciences beta](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/): see the [FAQ](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/faq). However your question would need to show some research effort, it's more a site for researchers, university level students and those who apply psychology/etc principles in their jobs.

Comment: Is observing just myself (maybe making a table of attempt number, game, time, subjective and objetive "successfulness" of attempt) enough "research effort" to open a question there?

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of topics that aren't (yet) covered by Stack Exchange sites.  With Area51, it is easy to add a topic, but you need at least 200 people to start a site. So if you really like an answer, take some effort into getting more people involved in the Area51 proposal.

If you are successful, you get an active community and a lot of Area51 badges.

An other alternative is to find an answer outside Stack Exchange, easier, but not as rewarding.